# Fixed header section with scrollable bottom section

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a layout where my client would like the header section to be fixed and the content of the page to be 100% of the available height and scrollable when there is overflow (so the page itself never scrolls).
[image]

The issue I'm working through is that the content for the header section is different on every page and needs to have a flexible height in cases where the user-generated header content gets really long and needs to wrap so I can't really set a fixed height. Here's what I have currently (with a height on the header)

CSS:

```
.header {
    background-color: #ffff00;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.content {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/2302/

It's a tricky layout - is this even possible? I'm sure this could be accomplished with Javascript but I'd really like to accomplish this with CSS if at all possible since the app will be quite large and I'd like something that is easy to maintain.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/2304/

Toughest part is accounting for the variable height of the header.

If you don't want to use javascript you could try something like this:

Render your `header` content twice. Once in an element with position fixed, and the second time as an element that's part of your normal document flow. By rendering the header a second time in the normal document flow your `bottom section` will be effectively pushed down by the height of the header. You can fix the other header to the top of the screen as you originally were.

Comment: Thanks thedeeno! This worked perfectly! Simple yet effective.